# AttributeError: 'GenericImport' object has no attribute 'account_import_set'

Tags: django

I have a model `AccountImport` that very clearly has a foreign key to `GenericImport`:

from django.db import models
from mcif.models.generic_import import GenericImport

```
class AccountImport(models.Model):

    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    generic_import = models.ForeignKey(GenericImport)
    is_entirely_international = models.IntegerField()
    is_queued = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'account_import'
        app_name = 'mcif'
```

And here's `GenericImport`:

```
from django.db import models
from mcif.models.import_profile import ImportProfile
from mcif.models.import_file import ImportFile
from mcif.models.import_bundle import ImportBundle
from mcif.models.customer import Customer
from mcif.models.csv_row import CSVRow
import csv, cStringIO

class GenericImport(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'generic_import'
        app_name = 'mcif'

    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    import_profile = models.ForeignKey(ImportProfile)
    import_file = models.ForeignKey(ImportFile)
    notes = models.TextField()
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
    active = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField()
    unsavable_rows = models.TextField()
    import_bundle = models.ForeignKey(ImportBundle)
    is_queued = models.IntegerField()

    @classmethod
    def last(cls):
        all = GenericImport.objects.all()
        return all[len(all) - 1]

    def process(self):
        for line in self.import_file.file.split("\n")[:30]:
            f = cStringIO.StringIO(line)
            row = CSVRow()
            row.array = next(csv.reader(f))
            row.generic_import = self
            row.process()
            f.close()
```

But watch what happens when I do this:

```
>>> from mcif.models.generic_import import GenericImport
>>> GenericImport.objects.all()[0].account_import_set.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'GenericImport' object has no attribute 'account_import_set'
```

Isn't that supposed to work? I don't understand what I could have done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be your model name in lowercase unless overriden by `related_name`. 
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

```
GenericImport.objects.latest('id').accountimport_set.all()
```